# Qualtrics- How to randomly alternate item type

Tags: alternate, qualtrics

I have two types of questions, each with 5 questions. For instance, questions A1, A2,...,A5 are about fruit and questions B1, B2,...,B5 are about vegetables.
I would like the questions to be displayed exactly once, in alternate order, randomly. For example, one participants might get the order B5, A1, B2, A3, B1, A4, B4, A5, B3, A2, while another participant might get A2, B1, A5, B3,...

The total 10 questions are currency listed within one block, but I could separate them into two blocks (by type), or into 10 different blocks, if needed to solve this issue.

I am hoping for a built-in solution in Qualtrics that doesn't require javascript (which I have never used), but if js is needed then I would appreciate some guidance on writing the proper code for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could achieve this using Survey Flow with the "**Randomizer**" element. Add a randomizer to your survey flow and underneath it you can nest blocks that you want to randomize.

For example, if you have 2 blocks of 5 questions each, you could randomize the blocks such that the respondent is presented with one or both of the blocks, in whatever randomization proportion you'd like (or randomize them evenly using the "Evenly Present Elements" checkbox).

You can position the randomizer element as you would any other element in your survey flow, so if you need to combine it with branch logic it is nestable.